# Is there a iOS library for a menu like Yelp?

Tags: ios, menu, yelp

I am building an iOS app for my university, but I am struggling with the question which Menu library I should use for building my "Start screen menu".

I like the menu style Yelp is using (see image below). Does anyone know if there is an iOS library for me to use, which has a similar menu like the menu in Yelp?

Thank you very much!

[image: The Yelp menu]

Answer (score 0):

Actually core iOS SDK contains a library that can achieve a very similar effect to what you posted on your screenshot. The element is called an `UICollectionView` and it's purpose is to create a collection of elements. See the following [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH1-SW1) for detailed information.

After you go through the guide, you will realise you can create a single `UICollectionViewCell` that has a button with an image. You can provide the contents of this cell via `UICollectionViewDataSource` and then respond to each specific cell being tapped via `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

The biggest problem I see would be creating those separator lines, but you can do this in code as well.